# How can I combine JSON rows in a logic app grouped by another property

Tags: arrays, json, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that is taking failed runs from an app writing to application insights, and I want to group all the errors by the operation name into a single message.  Can someone explain how to do this?

my starting data looks like:

```
[{ "messageError": "Notification sent to AppName but not received for request: 20200213215520_hUu22w9RZlyc, user email@email.com Status: NotFound", 
   "transactionKey": "20200213215520_hUu22w9RZlyc"},
 { "messageError": "App to App Import Request: 20200213215520_hUu22w9RZlyc from user email@email.com was unable to insert to following line(s) into App with error(s) :\r\n Line 123: Unable to unlock this record.", 
   "transactionKey": "20200213215520_hUu22w9RZlyc"}]
```

What I am trying to get out of that would be a single row that concatenates both messageError values into one statement on a common transaction key.  Something like this:

```
[{ "messageErrors": [{"Notification sent to AppName but not received for request: 20200213215520_hUu22w9RZlyc, user email@email.com Status: NotFound"}, 
                     {"App to App Import Request: 20200213215520_hUu22w9RZlyc from user email@email.com was unable to insert to following line(s) into App with error(s) :\r\n Line 123: Unable to unlock this record."}], 
   "transactionKey": "20200213215520_hUu22w9RZlyc"}]
```

There might be as many as 20 rows in the dataset, and the concatenation needs to be smart enough to group only if there are multiple rows with the same transactionKey.  Has anyone done this, and have a suggestion on how to group them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, I thought that we can use liquid template to do the "group by" operation for your json data at the beginning. But according to some test, it seems azure logic app doesn't support "group by" in its liquid template. So there two solutions for us to choose:

A. One solution is do these operations in logic app by "For each" loop, "If" condition, compose the json data and so many other actions, and also we have to initialize many variables. I tried this solution first, but I gave up it after creating so many actions in logic app. It's too complicated.

B. The other solution is call a azure function in logic app, and we can do the operations for the json data in function code. It's not easy either, but I think it's better than the first solution. So I tried this solution and got success. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** We need to [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function#create-a-function-app) a azure function app with a "HTTP" trigger in it.

**2.** In your "HTTP" trigger, please refer to my code below:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JArray array = JArray.Parse(body);

    JArray resultArray = new JArray();
    JObject tempObj = new JObject();

    foreach (var obj in array)
    {
        JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(obj.ToString());
        string transactionKey = jsonObj.GetValue("transactionKey").ToString();
        string messageError = jsonObj.GetValue("messageError").ToString();
        Boolean hasKey = false;
        foreach (var item in tempObj)
        {
            JObject jsonItem = (JObject)item.Value;
            string keyInItem = jsonItem.GetValue("transactionKey").ToString();
            if (transactionKey.Equals(keyInItem))
            {
                hasKey = true;
                break;
            }else
            {
                hasKey = false;
            }
        }
        if (hasKey.Equals(false))
        {
            JObject newObj = new JObject();
            JArray newArr = new JArray();
            newArr.Add(messageError);
            newObj.Add("transactionKey", transactionKey);
            newObj.Add("messageErrors", newArr);
            tempObj.Add(transactionKey, newObj);
        }
        else
        {
            JObject oldObj = (JObject)tempObj.GetValue(transactionKey);
            JArray oldArr = (JArray)oldObj.GetValue("messageErrors");
            oldArr.Add(messageError);
            oldObj.Property("messageErrors").Remove();
            oldObj.Add("messageErrors", oldArr);
            tempObj.Property(transactionKey).Remove();
            tempObj.Add(transactionKey, oldObj);
        }
    }

    foreach (var x in tempObj)
    {
        resultArray.Add(x.Value);
    }

    return resultArray;
}
```

**3.** Test and save the function, and then go to your logic app. In logic app, I initialize a variable named "data" with the json data below to simulate your scene.
[image]

**4.** Then [create function in your logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#create-functions-inside-logic-apps) and choose the "HTTP" trigger which you created just now.

**5.** After running the logic app, we can get the result shown as below:

```
[
  {
    "transactionKey": "20200213215520_hUu22w9RZlyc",
    "messageErrors": [
      "xxxxxxxxx",
      "yyyyyyyy"
    ]
  },
  {
    "transactionKey": "keykey",
    "messageErrors": [
      "testtest11",
      "testtest22",
      "testtest33"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll mark this as the answer because it solves the issue, although does leave the logic apps.  Would have been better using the Javascript step in a logic app which is what I am going to attempt using your code as the basis.